# the light doesnt bonces

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

the sunlight doesn't bounce like expected, don't matter what I do, false-color don't get that red to make it look like day, and the light lose strength fast, the room dont look like its geting light, light path is set do defout bounces, like 4 4 8 12 0
[image: with a 150000 strength sun]

[image: a 500000 sun]

[image: a 1000000 sun]

[image: a 1000000 sun without glass on windows]

[image: a 1GW area lamp without glass on window]

Comment: What type of light are you using, what's it's strength set to, and what look are you using?

Comment: Oh the description doesn't went,there os diferentes types, in the roll: a 150000 Sun; a 500000 Sun; a 1000000 sun; a 1000000 Sun withou Glass on Windows; a 1GW area without Glass on window

Comment: Are you using the denoiser? What happens if you disable that? Is the false color on a rendered, saved image?

Comment: yep I'm using a denoiser, didn't try to turn off, but I will, and yes a false-color save
the only thing that I did in a different way of other renders is that I star testing in Eevee than change to cycles to get the final, but I don't think that it changes the final in this way

Comment: iv tried with no denoiser, get the same thing in a bad quality kkkkk